# How can I swap each pair of values in an array in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how I can make a method that can swap each pair of values of an array.

For example -

```
 Input array:            3 1 2 6 
 Array after swap:       1 3 6 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

```
for (int x = 0; x < array.length - 1; x = x + 2) {
    int hold = array[x];        // So we don't lose it
    array[x] = array[x + 1];    // Make the second one the first one
    array[x + 1] = hold;        // Make the second one the original first 
}
```

Thank you, Jorn Vernee, for your recommendation.

Comment: should probably be ```x < array.length - 1``` to be safe for uneven length arrays. It will still work the same for even arrays.

Comment: It does, I just tested it. (in response to now deleted comment stating that it doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks guys how can i print it System.out.print(hold) ?

Comment: Iterate through the array for each element. Print that element. `for (int x : array) { System.out.print(x + " "); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

for(int i =0; i < array.length; i = i+2) {

    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    array[i+1] = temp; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: temp will hold x[i] data that is 1 
x[1] will hold the data x[i+1] =2
x[2] = temp
then 
2,1
i =i+2
i=3
temp =x[3]
x[3] = x[i+1]
x[4] = temp

4,3